# Why is water accumulating in my sump pail when there has been no rain?

Tags: sump-pump

My sump pump started kicking out water about the 3rd week in March (still cold here, no rain).  I had a plumber out and there is no water running in the house and we checked with the water service in the neighborhood and no increase in water usage within my house or surrounding homes.  Where could the water be coming from and who do I contact for help?

Comment: It would be groundwater, which is normally the reason there IS a sump pump... Contact your deity of choice, or a realtor if the idea of a sump doing its job bothers you that much.

Comment: Thawing soil releases lots of water, which can raise the table.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, there are too many possibilities for us to give  you a single "good" answer.

Comment: Even though you're not seeing any extra metered usage, it's also possible that there is a leak on the water company's side of the meter and the water is following the pipe to your house and finding its way into the sump.